# Step by step long division in Java?

Tags: java, division

I'm trying to write a function that outputs a step by step long division problem given a dividend and a divisor. It's supposed to look like this:

```
     25 r 2                            
5 | 125                     
   -10                                 
     27                          
    -25                          
      2
```

I can write the bit with the vertical line easily enough, but I can't figure out how to format the top part with the remainder or the subtraction loop. Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: In your example, is 125 the dividend and 5 the divisor? If so there should be no remainder.

Comment: yes the OP mistakenly added the 2 from the first subtraction to both digits of the second line, I think.

Comment: You should show us what code you have done so far.  There's also some question how much wiggle room there is in your spec, how much white space for example could be added if some of the relative positions of the numbers don't shift.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to this problem, you might want to implement some error checking to see if the dividend is larger than the divisor. The spacing might not always work, but I tried with a few numbers and it seemed fine:

```
int divisor = 5;
int dividend = 127;
int answer = dividend / divisor;

// Set a space constant for formatting
int spaces = (int) Math.log10(dividend) + (int) Math.log10(divisor) + 4;

// Print the initial bracket
for(int i = 0; i < spaces - (int) Math.log10(answer); i ++)  {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.println(Integer.toString(answer) + " r " + Integer.toString(dividend % divisor));
System.out.println(Integer.toString(divisor) + " | " + Integer.toString(dividend));

// Do a while loop to do the subtraction
int remainder = dividend;
while(remainder != dividend % divisor) {
    
    // Find how much of the start of the remainder can be subtracted by making it into a string
    String test = Integer.toString(remainder);
    int sub = Integer.valueOf(test.substring(0, 1));
    test = test.substring(1);
    int exp = (int) Math.log10(remainder);
    while(sub < divisor) {
        sub = sub * 10 + Integer.valueOf(test.substring(0, 1));
        test = test.substring(1);
        exp--;
    }
    
    int multiple = sub - (sub % divisor);
    
    //Print the subtraction and remainder lines
    for(int i = 0; i < spaces - 1 - exp - (int) Math.log10(multiple); i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("-" + Integer.valueOf(multiple));
    
    remainder -= multiple * Math.pow(10, exp);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < spaces - (int) Math.log10(remainder); i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(remainder));

}
```

The tricky part was working out how much of the remainder needed to be isolated (for example with 127 and 5, 1 cannot be divided by 5, so I needed to use 12) which I achieved by making the remainder into a String to interpret it one character at a time (this can be done mathematically but it hurt my head when it didn't work on my first try so I gave up).

Sample output for dividend = 12, divisor = 5:

```
     25 r 2
5 | 127
   -10
     27
    -25
      2
```

Comment: Sometimes I think that " From which planet have you learnt java" for the persons who answer this type of questions. :—)

Answer (score 0):

Populate an object and then call to print format.

**LongDivision.java**

```
public class LongDivision {
    /**
     * The Number.
     */
    String number;
    /**
     * The Divider.
     */
    String divider;
    /**
     * The Result.
     */
    String result;
    /**
     * The Lines.
     */
    List<String> lines;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Long divider.
     *
     * @param number  the number
     * @param divider the divider
     * @param result  the result
     * @param lines   the lines
     */
    public LongDivision(String number, String divider, String result, List<String> lines) {
        this.number = number;
        this.divider = divider;
        this.result = result;
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    /**
     * Gets number.
     *
     * @return the number
     */
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    /**
     * Sets number.
     *
     * @param number the number
     */
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    /**
     * Gets divider.
     *
     * @return the divider
     */
    public String getDivider() {
        return divider;
    }

    /**
     * Sets divider.
     *
     * @param divider the divider
     */
    public void setDivider(String divider) {
        this.divider = divider;
    }

    /**
     * Gets result.
     *
     * @return the result
     */
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Sets result.
     *
     * @param result the result
     */
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets lines.
     *
     * @return the lines
     */
    public List<String> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    /**
     * Sets lines.
     *
     * @param lines the lines
     */
    public void setLines(List<String> lines) {
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "LongDivider (number=%s, divider=%s, result=%s, lines=%s)", this.number, this.divider, this.result, this.lines);
    }

    /**
     * print format.
     *
     * @return the string
     */
    public String printFormat() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(result+"\n");
        stringBuilder.append(repeat("__", 2));
        stringBuilder.append("\n");
        stringBuilder.append(number + "| " + divider);
        stringBuilder.append("\n");
        lines.stream().forEach(s -> stringBuilder.append(s+"\n"));
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static String repeat(String s, int n) {
        if(s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() * n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class LongDividerSolution {
    /**
     * The entry point of application.
     *
     * @param args the input arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = "945";
        String divider = "4";
        String result = "236 (1)";
        String lineSeparator = "_";
        int max = Math.max(number.length(), result.length());
        // TODO Implement the calculation itself.
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("8");
        strings.add(LongDivision.repeat(lineSeparator, max));
        strings.add("14");
        strings.add(" 12");
        strings.add(LongDivision.repeat(lineSeparator,max));
        strings.add("  25");
        strings.add("   24");
        strings.add(LongDivision.repeat(lineSeparator,max));
        strings.add("( 1 )");
        LongDivision longDivision = new LongDivision(number, divider, result,strings);
        System.out.println(longDivision.printFormat());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
236 (1)
___
945| 4
8
_____
14
 12
_____
  25
   24
_____
( 1 )
```